# How to chain two routers so each provides its own WPA2 network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have two wifi+ethernet routers, one somewhat older ASUS RT-N11, the other a new TP-Link TL-WR941ND. The computers on our home network all support "n" wifi, except for one old Dell laptop that my wife refuses to abandon, but wants it to use wifi. My understanding is that having this machine sharing a wifi network with the others will slow everybody down to "g" speeds.

How can I configure the routers so that each can have its own wifi network (one exclusively for the older machine), but all machines can talk to one another, with no ip address collisions?

Thanks and regards,

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid (although it actually it's a good thing ;-) that your understanding is incorrect. 802.11n is backwards-compatible with 802.11a/b/g (or if not, almost all routers support all 4 techs). Your wife's computer may be slower than your 802.11n computer, but it won't slow everyone else's speeds down any more than adding a machine with 802.11n would.

Summary: having an older wifi device on a newer network won't make the rest of the network any more slower than it would with a newer device would.